# How to use the server stored socket I'd on Cross domain client socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, cross-domain

I'm using socket.io for sending the data to cross domain, but the cross domain socket.id gives the unique id for the socket(client) , I want to use the particular server socket I'd on client side at cross domain.

I try this method

```
server side
io.emit('sendsocketid', id);

Crossdomain clientside
var socket = io('https://localhost:3000/', { transports: ['websocket'] });

socket.on('sendsocketid', function (id) {
    console.log(id);

})
```

I've successfully emit the server socket.id on Crossdomain client, but
I want only use the `server_socket.id` on cross domain client.
How to customize the `client's_socket.id` at cross domain?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured it out yet??

Comment: @Bombosonic
 No, Not yet!

Comment: I am having a problem like this too.. I'm trying to connect to some server.. you on discord??

Comment: @Bombosonic I'm not in discord! I'll give you my mail id maran101297@gmail.com

Comment: OK I'll text you now abombshell9@gmail.com